# How do I delete every line from a file matching the first line

Tags: bash, sed

I want to delete every line of a file that matches the first line, but not delete the first line.

I've tried this code so far, but it deletes all matching patterns including the first line.

```
sed -i "1,/$VARIABLE_CONTAINING_PATTERN/d" $MY_FILE.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to delete lines with the pattern `$VARIABLE_CONTAINING_PATTERN` or lines that match the first line of your file?

Comment: Lines that match the first line of my file

Comment: You might try this `sed -i "/$VARIABLE_CONTAINING_PATTERN/{1!d}" $MY_FILE.txt`

Comment: in this case, no need for `$VARIABLE_CONTAINING_PATTERN`, cause the first line will be a pattern

Answer (score 2):

Following your description literally - *to delete every line of a file that matches the first line, but not delete the first line*, ***awk*** solution:

Let's say we have the following `myfile.txt`:

```
my pattern
some text
another pattern
regex
awk sed
my pattern
text text
my pattern
our patterns
```

---

```
awk 'NR==1{ pat=$0; print }NR>1 && $0!~pat' myfile.txt > tmp && mv tmp myfile.txt
```

---

Final `myfile.txt` contents:

```
my pattern
some text
another pattern
regex
awk sed
text text
our patterns
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk. Solution depends a bit on your definition of a *match*:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
1
12
$ awk 'NR==1{p=$0;print;next} p $0 != p' file
1
2
3
12
$ awk 'NR==1{p=$0;print;next} $0 !~ p' file
1
2
3
```

Therefore you should provide proper sample data with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '1h;1!G;/^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P;d' file
```

Copy the first line into the hold space (HS). For every line except the first, append the HS to the pattern space (PS). Compare the current line to the first line and print the current line if it is not the same. Delete the pattern space.